# XP machine fails to boot

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I have an XP machine that is still used by family and it is not booting anymore. It stops at a black screen with a blinking underline. When I booted to a xp disk and got to the repair console, I did a fixboot and fixmbr and then it would boot to a choose your os screen, only listing the recovery console. I tried bootcfg /rebuild but it gives me an error saying the file system may be corrupt. chkdsk /f /r shows no errors. I booted to hirens and replaced the contents of the boot.ini file with ones i found online that are the defaults, but it sill just sits at the black screen with the curser.

Any other ideas? I would just re-install but I won't be able to activate...

EDIT: I re-installed xp but can't find drivers for the machine, so I grabbed it's config files (like boot.ini) and re-imaged back to before the install. I copied over the files and now I get the boot options screen that seems to try to boot, but now it can't find hal.dll...

Spinrite shows the drive is otherwise fine. The issue may be the file system i guess, it just seems that at this point, there is no re-install option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with the drivers you must install the windows version that originally came with the system and download them right from the manufacturer's website. Alternatively, you can connect to the internet and make the *Device Manager* to automatically install the drivers for your devices, but this doesn't work always.

Also, just copy-pasting configuration files from one system to another is one of the **worst** things you can do. Avoid this at all costs.

By the way, why didn't it boot in the first place? Did you install something prior to this?

Comment: It had viruses. The HP site doesn't list network XP drivers for this machine, so I will try the Vista ones. Without the network drivers, I can't auto download any others

Comment: I have an HP XP MCE disk that will accept his key, my concern is activation, updates and drivers.

Comment: As I said before, you have to install the OS version that originally came with your machine. If the HP site only lists Vista drivers it's because that machine was made for Vista and you should install it, either that or you could manually look for drivers for your devices by looking for their hardware ids on the internet (but I wouldn't do this unless it's the last resort).